# Optimisation model, skip error due to index componenet

Tags: python, optimization, model, pyomo

I have an index error on one of the components of my objective function and I wanted to know if there's a way to tell pyomo to skip the index component when there's none.

To clarify, I have a dictionary Penalty_Nu[n, s, d] with only the indexes componenents when the penalty should be applied.

Model.x is a variable of all [n, s, d] component where:

- N: employee ID
- S: Shifts
- D: Day

Here's the part of the objective function:

```
def obj_function(model):
     return(
         sum(sum(Penalty_Nu[n,s,d]*model.x[n,s,d] for d in model.D) for s in model.S)
     )
    
model.ObjFunction = Objective(rule=obj_function, sense=minimize)
```

Here's the error:

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for objective ObjFunction:
    KeyError: (9, 'N', 2)
ERROR: Constructing component 'ObjFunction' from data=None failed: KeyError:
    (9, 'N', 2)
```

I know I could add all the components[n, s, d] where the penality should be 0 to the dictionary Penalty_Nu but if there's another way it could really help me.

Answer (score 0):

def obj_function(model):
return(
sum(sum(Penalty_Nu[n,s,d]*model.x[n,s,d] for d in model.D) for s in model.S)
)

the n index is missing in your summation , correct it as follows:

```
def obj_function(model):
 return sum(Penalty_Nu[n,s,d]*model.x[n,s,d] for d in model.D for s in model.S for n in model.N)
```

you have three indices and the summation should be over all of them Objective function can not have index